# python memory allocation when using chr()

Tags: python

I am new to python and I want to have a list with 2 elements the first one is an integer between 0 and 2 billion, the other one is a number between 0 to 10. I have a large number of these lists (billions).

Suppose I use chr() function to add the second argument for the list. For example:

```
first_number = 123456678
second_number = chr(1)
mylist = [first_number,second_number]
```

In this case how does python allocate memory? Will it assume that the second argument is a char and give it (1 byte + overheads) or will it assume that the second argument is a string? If it thinks that it is a string is there any way that I can define and enforce something as char or make this some how more memory efficient?

**Edit --> added some more information about why I need this data structure**

Here is some more information about what I want to do:

I have a sparse weighted graph with 2 billion edges and 25 million nodes. To represent this graph I tried to create a dictionary (because I need a fast lookup) in which the keys are the nodes (as integers). These nodes are represented by a number between 0 to 2 billion (there is no relation between this and the number of edges). The edges are represented like this: For each of the nodes (or the keys in the dictionary ) I am keeping a list of list. Each element of this list of list is a list that I have explained above. The first one represent the other node and the second argument represents the weight of the edge between the key and the first argument. For example, for a graph that contain 5 nodes, if I have something like

```
 {1: [[2, 1], [3, 1], [4, 2], [5, 1]], 2: [[5, 1]], 3: [[5, 2]], 4: [[6, 1]], 5: [[6, 1]]}
```

it means that node 1 has 4 edges: one that goes to node 2 with weight 1, one that goes to node 3, with weight 1, one that goes to node 4 with weight 2, etc.

I was looking to see if I could make this more memory efficient by making the second argument of the edge smaller.

Comment: There is no "char" type in python.

Comment: Python doesn't make a distinction between characters and strings; "characters" are just 1-length strings.

Comment: It's going to be difficult in Python to closely control how memory is allocated.  You might have to rethink your approach.  If you can describe the problem more, we might have better answers.

Comment: What Ned said; in particular, if you're coming from C-family languages you'll probably be startled by the amount of memory overhead in Python objects.

Comment: Python caches small integers (and small strings). You should not worry about it unless you start getting errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a single character string will take up about the same amount memory as a small integer because CPython will only create one object of each value, and use that object every time it needs a string or integer of that value. Using strings will take up a bit more space, but it'll be insignificant.

But lets answer you real question, how can you reduce the amount of memory your Python program uses? First I'll calculate about how much memory the objects you want to create will use. I'm using the 64-bit version of Python 2.7 to get my numbers but other 64-bit versions of Python should be similar.

Starting off you have only one `dict` object, but it has 25 million nodes. Python will use 2^26 hash buckets for a dict of this size, and each bucket is 24 bytes. That comes to about 1.5 GB for the dict itself.

The dict will have 25 million keys, all of them `int` objects, and each of them is 24 bytes. That comes to total of about 570 MB for all the integers that represent nodes. It will also have 25 million `list` objects as values. Each list will take up 72 bytes plus 8 bytes per element in the list. These lists will have a total of 2 billion elements, so they'll take up a total of 16.6 GB.

Each of these 2 billion list elements will refer to another `list` object that's two elements long. That comes to whopping 164 GB. Each of the two element lists will refer two different `int` objects. Now the good news, while that appears to be a total of about 4 billion integer objects, it's actually only 2 billion different integer objects. There will be only one object created for each of the small integer values used in the second element. So that's a total 44.7 GB of memory used by the integer objects referred to by the first element.

That comes to at least 227 GB of memory you'll need for the data structure as you plan to implement it. Working back through this list I'll explain how its possible for you reduce the memory you'll need to something more practical.

The 44.7 GB of memory used by the `int` objects that represent nodes in your two element edge lists is the easiest to deal with. Since there are only 25 million nodes, you don't need 2 billion different objects, just one for each node value. Also since you're already using the node values as keys you can just reuse those objects. So that's 44.7 GB gone right there, and depending on how you build your data structure it might not take much effort to ensure only that no redudant node value objects are created. That brings the total down to 183 GB.

Next lets tackle the 164 GB needed for all the two element edge `list` objects. It's possible that you can share list objects that happen to have the same node value and weighting, but you can do better. Eliminate all the edges lists by flatting the lists of lists. You'll have to do a bit arithmetic access the correct elements, but unless you have a system with a huge amount of memory you're going to have to make compromises. The `list` objects used as dict values will have to double in length, increasing their total size from 16.1 GB to 31.5 GB.  That makes your net savings from flatting the lists a nice 149 GB, bringing the total down to a more reasonable 33.5 GB.

Going farther than this is trickier. One possibility is to use arrays. Unlike lists their elements don't refer to other objects, the value is stored in each element. An `array.array` object is 56 bytes long plus the size of the elements which in this case are 32-bit integers. That adds up to 16.2 GB for a net savings of 15.3 GB. The total is now only 18.3 GB.

It's possible to squeeze a little more space by taking advantage of the fact that your weights are small integers that fit in single byte characters. Create two `array.array` objects for each node, one with 32-bit integers for the node values, and the other with 8-bit integers for the weights. Because there are now two array objects, use a `tuple` object to hold the pair. The total size of all these objects is 13.6 GB. Not a big savings over a single array but now you don't need to any arithmetic to access elements, you just need switch how you index them. The total is down to 15.66 GB.

Finally the last thing I can think of to save memory is to only have two `array.array` objects. The dict values then become `tuple` objects that refer to two `int` objects. The first is an index into the two arrays, the second is a length. This representation takes up 11.6 GB of memory, another small net decrease, with the total becoming 13.6 GB.

That final total of 13.6 GB should work on machine with 16 GB of RAM without much swapping, but it won't leave much room for anything else.

Comment: I just had one question: You have mentioned "Since there are only 25 million nodes, you don't need 2 billion different objects, just one for each node value. Also since you're already using the node values as keys you can just reuse those objects." In python, if I put an integer in a container and refer to that will it be by ref? For example if I define a[0] = 1234; b[0] = a[0]; will it create an integer or will it just reuse a[0]?

Comment: It will use the same `int` object. Generally Python doesn't create a new object if it hasn't be asked to. So `b = a` results in `b` and `a` referring to the same `list` object. `b = a[:]` creates a new list that refer to the same objects. `b[:] = a[:]` reuses the `list` object referred to by `b`, making it refer to same objects as `a`.